# Execute multiple commands on remote machine

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, command

In the following command i am trying to ssh commands and execute the multiple commands.How can i exit if any of the command fails i.e, if !command1 exit then if !command1 and !commnd 2 exit else execute command 3 on the remote machine.How can i achieve this

```
 ssh login.com "git clone --bare new@login2.com/repo/ /home/usr1/repo/ && \
                cd /home/usr1/repo/info/                               && \
                echo "hello world" > .a.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your quotes don't conflict:

```
ssh login.com \
   'git clone --bare new@login2.com/repo/ /home/usr1/repo/ &&
    cd /home/usr1/repo/info/ &&
    echo "hello world" > .a.txt'
```

This assumes you wanted to leave a.txt on the server, otherwiseL

```
ssh login.com \
   'git clone --bare new@login2.com/repo/ /home/usr1/repo/ &&
    cd /home/usr1/repo/info/ &&
    echo "hello world"' > .a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have there will do it — the `&&` chaining will mean the next command only runs if the previous succeeded.

```
$ true && false && echo "here"
$ true && true && echo "here"
here
$
```

Comment: obviously, the OP knows about that. You didn't address the actual problem

Comment: Uuhh... Why is that obvious? If he obviously knew it, why would he be asking the question?

Comment: Ok in fairness, the wording of the Q _is_ unclear.  **But** the question clearly shows the exact same method you show, leading me to conclude that the broken quoting is more likely the problem