# How to create a user on Ubuntu machine from a C# program?

Tags: c#

I have never worked with networking, and I have a task with it:
On virtual mashine I have a Ubuntu on real mashine I have a Windows;
I need to write a programm in Windows, which is create a user in Ubuntu.
Network connection is setup, mashines are pinging.
I try to use a NFS(Netwerk File System) but I dont know nothing about it... Please help, push me in right side.
How I can do it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install [gnu tools](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) for windows.
- Write a script to [create a user](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-new-linux-user-account/) on remote machine using ssh
- invoke the script from C# program as a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx).

See [Execute multiple commands on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817950/execute-multiple-commands-on-remote-machine)

Comment: I don't understand, why it's not work. I download a WinSCP and try to connect with my virtual machine typing in Host name Ubuntu IP, and have a error connection refused. What I did wrong?

Comment: @Alexander you have to configure your Ubuntu machine to accept ssh connections. Please post a question on how to do that on serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, but when I show my solution, I was told, that I need to create a pure program without of using ssh clients. I can use only different .dll's.