# Create user on Ubuntu from Windows in C#

Tags: c#, networking, ubuntu

I'm already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363871/how-to-create-a-user-on-ubuntu-machine-from-a-c-sharp-program), but how I was told, I need to create a proggram without of using ssh clients. How do I say I need to write pure C# program using only different .dll's. And I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: To answer the "how to" part you first need to know what network access methods are allowed. With ssh being the standard way to remotely access Ubuntu machines the one denying SSH as an option has to answer what other options you have first. Then you can come back here and ask for help on how to implement that in C#.

Comment: According to the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363871/how-to-create-a-user-on-ubuntu-machine-from-a-c-sharp-program), someone suggested posting this question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/), so you may have better luck there.

Comment: I can think of many very insecure ways (and not reliable) but they require lots of creativity. You could set up a cron job to check for a file in a specific folder (that could be placed there with ftp) and run the create user script with info from that file. You could also use a Database and a cron job. I wouldn't advise this but if you need to do it then....

Comment: I think i need only safe access to ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement a proper solution you want to use [OpenLDAP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openldap/).

You can then use C# to query the LDAP database and use that to create accounts remotely.

Comment: This is probably the most reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done because you want to gain remote access to the linux system you need to use ssh to gain access to the command line to make your users. Look into ssh there are some good clients for windows that allow you this access and I am sure I found some tutorials on how to make a ssh program a while back.

Comment: I can use ssh dll's, but I don't know nothing about it.

Comment: I don't know is this is any good but have a look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11966/sharpSsh-A-Secure-Shell-SSH-library-for-NET it gives source code don't know how helpful that is.

Answer (score 1):

So since you can't use ssh, it is time to get creative!
I'm assuming you have admin rights. Let me know if you don't.

Set up a database (MySQL) on the Ubuntu box, and create a db/table with the new users to be created. You can insert a row from C# into that table.

Set up a cron job, or some other application (in python, c++, w/e you like) that would periodically check for a new row in that table. If it finds one, extract the data, create the user based on that data, and remove the row. This would have to run as root so BE CAREFUL!

I have done something like this before and it is messy and convoluted, but it works, i guess.

Comment: Thanks, I think if I do it with MySQL, I'll be wrong again, because I need to write pure C# program.

Comment: As far as I know MySQL works with c# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL